# How to Overwrite Database Table Data Using SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-datatools, sqlpackage, sql-data-tools

I'm currently working on a small project using sql data tools. I'm getting data from excel sheet and write it back to my database table. from the database table I'm generating a report. Time to time I'm updating my excel sheet. but it won't update in my database table. how do I clear the table and rewrite excel sheet data to database table when run the project every time?

Answer (score 0):

post build script would be how and when I would clear or synchronize the data.  Then you have to write the truncate or delete and the insert and/or update sections to move data from your excel document to the sql table.  I would suspect that the SQL table is a better place to maintain the data though!!!  If you maintain in SQL you can always have a query to see what it is in Excel at any given time and you don't have to worry about synching back to SQL.